# Dropdown list in admin registration panel Django

Tags: django, authentication, dropdown, admin, panel

I would like to have a dropdown list in the login field of authenti(fi)cation panel in Django : for admin and for a worker. Do you have any idea how to implement it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you asking about a drop down choice field? This should be implemented within the model